# Check if the value "false" is in a range using FormatConditions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Quick question here guys, I've been searching around on how to use formatConditions in VBA and I didn't find exactly what I wanted.

I know how to make new rules in excel normally, but I have to make this one via VBA.

I'll try to explain this with comments on my code:

```
 With Range(Cells(5, 11), Cells(comparisonlastrow, 11))
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    'Add formatcondition rule saying that if a cell in this range contains "false", this cell goes vbRed 
    '.
End With
Next
```

Comment: Why don't you try recording a `macro` while performing `conditional formatting` "normally", I hope it will give you a start point at least.

Comment: @YVXS I don't know how precisely macro recording works but the reason I don't use conditional formatting via non-vba is that the sheet that I'm working with only creates itself after running the VBA Macro to start with, would this change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can add conditional formatting using `VBA`. You can play around a bit with the sample code to get desired output.

```
FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=FALSE"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

First Edit:

I assume that you want to apply conditional formatting for a certain range (sort of loop), this is what you can do

```
Sub Cformatting()

Dim i

For i = 1 To 1000
    Range("E" & i).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=FALSE"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: it was giving me "Object Required" error in the first line, I edited the code to ".FormatConditions (etc)" and now it gives me subscription out of range in "Selection.FormatConditions(etc)"